# Matlab Error: 'Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.' when using ContinuousValueChange listener

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm fairly new to MATLAB.

I am trying to add a slider as a ContinuousValueChange listener to continuously display pictures through an axis using GUIDE. I already have the basic functionality of the slider working (i.e. a mouse click in the slider will change the picture accordingly), but I would like to implement continuous updating by dragging the slider.

For some reason, when I try to update the picture using the value from the continuous change I get an error. I peg this error to be strange because I do not receive it when simply clicking on the slider nor do I receive it when I use the next/previous buttons in my GUI

Code:

```
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.sliderListener = addlistener(handles.slider1,'ContinuousValueChange', ...
                                     @(a,b) continuousUpdate(handles));


% function to update displayed picture/counter upon change 
function updatePicture(handles)
guiControl = gcf;
files = getappdata(guiControl, 'currentPics');
i = getappdata(guiControl, 'currentCounter');
length = max(size(files));
img = imread(files{i});
imageHandle = imshow(img);
imagesc(img);
% update slider 
step = 1/(length - 1);
set(handles.slider1, 'SliderStep', [step step]);
set(handles.slider1, 'Max',        length);

function continuousUpdate(handles)
currentValue = get(handles.slider1, 'Value');
setappdata(gcf, 'currentCounter', round(currentValue));
guidata(handles.slider1, handles);
disp(currentValue);
updatePicture(handles);
```

Error:

```
Warning: Error occurred while executing the listener callback for event ContinuousValueChange defined for class matlab.ui.control.UIControl:
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in test>updatePicture (line 287)
img = imread(files{i});

Error in test>continuousUpdate (line 582)
updatePicture(handles);

Error in test>@(a,b)continuousUpdate(handles) (line 263)
                                           @(a,b) continuousUpdate(handles));
```

Comment: Variables `files` is empty which is likely due to the appdata currentPics being empty

Comment: But `files` is not empty when simply clicking on the slider so why would it be empty when dragging? @Random-Guy